# Boton con posicion random en la pantalla

Tags: botón, random

Quiero saber como hacer para que un boton aparezca en una posicion aleatoria de la pantalla (sobre los demas elementos de la pagina) cada vez que se recarga la pagina.
El boton es este:

`<a class="button" id="btn-exchange" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="start_timer();openWin('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Visit Site</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con JavaScript, lo primero que hice fue obtener las dimensiones del documento y luego del botón para poder moverme entre ese espectro visual; posteriormente aplique una operación matemática donde inclui la función **Math.random()** para arrojar valores Randon y luego se los setie al bóton en sus atributos **left** y **top** para moverlo; para que pudieses ver como lo hace aplique un **setTimeout** para que veas como cambia cada segundo pero tu se lo quitas y refrescas la pantalla y listo tendras un botón que aparece en un lugar diferente cada vez:

```js
const posicion = () => {
  
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn-exchange');
  let btnWidth = btn.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let btnHeight = btn.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  
  let docWidth = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let docHeight = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  
  let posx = (Math.random() * (docWidth - btnWidth)).toFixed();
  let posy = (Math.random() * (btnHeight - docHeight)).toFixed();
  
  btn.style.left = posx+'px';
  btn.style.top = posy+'px';
  
  setTimeout(function(){ posicion(); }, 1000);

}

posicion();
```

```css
.button{
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius:3px;
  padding:5px;
  position:absolute;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" id="btn-exchange" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="start_timer();openWin('<?php echo $url; ?>');">Visit Site</a>
```

Espero te sirva.